# get a single Thread from ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, pool, executor, threadpoolexecutor

I am running a ThreadPoolExecutor with a number of Threads.
I want to manipulate some data in the Threads, so I want to send an object to
the thread and after it finishes use the data.
The only way I know how is to wait until the thread finished with join()
and then use the data.
The problem is, that I can't get a single thread from the ThreadPoolExecutor.
I would like to do something like this:

```
Thread t = ThreadPoolExecutor.getThread();
t.start();
t.join();
```

rest of code....

Does anyone have a way?
I know that I can use Callable but I want to avoid this, as I already have pre-existing code...

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can `submit`, get a `Future` back and `get()` on the `Future`

```
Future<SomeResult> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<SomeResult>(){
    public SomeResult call(){
        //do work
        return new SomeResult();
    }
});

future.get();//suspends the current thread until the SomeResult callable returns.
```

Basically, the `call()` invocation is done on one of the Threads in the pool and the `get()` suspends the current thread similar to how `t.join()` suspends the current thread.